# Errors with MonoDevelop HelloWorld

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Currently following the HelloWorld Tutorial on the [monotouch website](http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld).

I add the following code as per the tutorial:

```
        int ntaps = 0;
        button.TouchDown += delegate { 
            label.Text = "I have been tapped " (++ntaps) + " times";
        };
```

However, when I build I get this error in regards to line 3 of the code above: "Expression denotes a 'value', where a 'method group' was expected".

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a plus operator in the string concatenation:

```
int ntaps = 0;
button.TouchDown += delegate { 
    label.Text = "I have been tapped " + (++ntaps) + " times";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the + after "I have been tapped ";

```
    int ntaps = 0;
    button.TouchDown += delegate { 
        label.Text = "I have been tapped " + (++ntaps) + " times";
    };
```